# How to derive the equation $I-\hat x \hat x^T= (\hat x^T E)^T(\hat x^T E)$

Tags: matrices

I encountered the above question in the paper. I have no idea how to obtain the right entry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

$$I-\hat x \hat x^T= (\hat x^T E)^T(\hat x^T E)$$

where $\hat x = \frac{x}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert}, x\in \mathbb R^2$, and $E=\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&1\\
{ - 1}&0
\end{array}} \right]$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If $\hat{x}$ is a $2 \times 1$ column vector and $E$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, how is $\hat{x} E$ defined?

Comment: Thanks to angryavian, a correction has been made.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is interesting, since for *any* vector $x=\pmatrix{a\\b}\;$ the product $E^Tx=\pmatrix{-b\\+a}\;$ and so $\,x\perp E^Tx$

${\mathbb R}^{2}$ is interesting, since *any* orthonormal vector pair $(x,y)$ forms a basis and so $\;I = xx^T + yy^T$

Combining these two interesting facts one can write
$$\eqalign{
I - xx^T &= yy^T \\&= (E^Tx)(E^Tx)^T \\&= (x^TE)^T(x^TE)
}$$

Answer (score 0):

You now that $|\hat x|=1$, so we can write $$\hat x=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $$\begin{align}I-xx^T&=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}1-\cos^2\theta&-\sin\theta\cos\theta\\-\sin\theta\cos\theta&1-\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}\sin^2\theta&-\sin\theta\cos\theta\\-\sin\theta\cos\theta&\cos^2\theta\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
For the other side of the equation
$$x^TE=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
Transpose it, do the last multiplication, and compare to the left hand side